# Does Ubuntu Core support IPv6?

Tags: ubuntu-core, ipv6

Does Ubuntu Core support IPV6?

Answer (score -1):

If you have modern distributive (kernel 2.6.x and up) - yes. Here is step-by-step instruction how to check it: http://mirrors.deepspace6.net/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/systemcheck-kernel.html